# GrantPermissionRule stopped working

Tags: android, testing-support-library

The GrantPermissionRule that I *successfully* implemented in my Android app on 1/3/2018 no longer works.  When I run my Espresso tests through Android Studio, the emulator blocks waiting for permissions.  However, when I run the tests from the command line with `./gradlew dist; ./gradlew connectedDebugAndroidTest --stacktrace` it doesn't ask for the permissions.  Note I do wipe data from the emulator manually before each run to ensure it's a proper test of GrantPermissionRule.

Here are the original references I used to implement GrantPermissionRule:
https://www.kotlindevelopment.com/runtime-permissions-espresso-done-right/ https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/rule/GrantPermissionRule.html

Versions in app/build.gradle:

- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:'3.0.1'
- com.android.support.test:runner:'1.0.1'

Has GrantPermissionRule stopped working as-advertised for anyone else?

Answer (score 6):

I tried using

```
@Rule 
public GrantPermissionRule mRuntimePermissionRule = GrantPermissionRule.grant(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
```

And this did not work. The permission alerts still show up when I run my espresso tests. This has been working for me though:

```
@Before
public void grantPhonePermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation().executeShellCommand(
                "pm grant " + getTargetContext().getPackageName()
                        + " android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was trying to automate Location permissions in Espresso UI tests on **Emulator Pixel 2 API R**.

**UseCase 1:**

When I was adding both ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION & ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION in **GrantPermissionRule** then RunTime permission popup was not auto disappearing.

**Not Working:**

```
@Rule
@JvmField
val grantPermissionRule: GrantPermissionRule = 
GrantPermissionRule.grant(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, 
android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
```

Then I removed ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION from **GrantPermissionRule** and the automation starts working.

**Working:**

```
@Rule
@JvmField
val grantPermissionRule: GrantPermissionRule = 
GrantPermissionRule.grant(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
```

**UseCase 2:**

Also below implementation working as above mentioned (failure/success)use-case.

**Not Working:**

```
@Before
fun grantPhonePermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        getInstrumentation().uiAutomation.executeShellCommand(
            "pm grant " + getApplicationContext<Context>()
                .packageName
                    + " android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
        )
        getInstrumentation().uiAutomation.executeShellCommand(
            "pm grant " + getApplicationContext<Context>()
                .packageName
                    + " android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"
        )
    }
}
```

**Working:**

```
@Before
fun grantPhonePermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        getInstrumentation().uiAutomation.executeShellCommand(
            "pm grant " + getApplicationContext<Context>()
                .packageName
                    + " android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: This above-mentioned behavior is also devices dependant. It does not work on real device Nexus 6P, please try to use another device.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to have disappeared, perhaps because I had to downgrade the Android Emulator to work around another issue (Here's [How to downgrade Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49120854/how-to-downgrade-android-emulator?rq=1)).