# Android Studio Emulator Error Using AVD

Tags: android-studio-3.0

I've been running Studio 3.0.1 for a few weeks. My project was working fine with the emulator and AVD. The next day, the first time I re-tried the emulator I got:

Emulator: emulator: ERROR: can't find the emulator executable

Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1

I have deleted and rebuilt a couple of different AVD devices, I checked that HAXM is running and my environment/system PATH variables are:

c:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\emulator

c:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools

c:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools

I then connected a Galaxy S7 running Nougat and the emulator runs fine!

Further investigation shows that when I run the emulator from the terminal: 
C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools>emulator -avd Samsung_Galaxy_S7_API_24

I get:
Could not launch 'C:\Users\DHJ\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools..\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-i386.exe': No such file or directory

And when I run it from a different folder (why are there 2 locations for the emulator?):
C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\emulator>emulator -avd Samsung_Galaxy_S7_API_24

I get: 
emulator: ERROR: can't find the emulator executable.

Any ideas on how I can AVD working again?

Comment: Since this isn't going away, is there a part of AS that I can remove/re-install- maybe the emulator or AVD? Or is a full removal and re-installation needed?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this by downgrading the emulator using the reply from:

[How to downgrade Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49120854/how-to-downgrade-android-emulator)