# android studio emulator crashing after 3.0 update

Tags: android, android-emulator, cocos2d-x

I have been messing around with android studio and I ended up installing cocos2dx and using an arm cpu emulator to work with cocos2dx. I have recently seen a message prompting for an update for the android emulator service so I installed it and now my emulator crashes while trying to boot and gives this error in the logcat - this is the error it gave me

```
19:36   Emulator: **

19:36   Emulator: ERROR:/buildbot/src/android/emu-3.0-release/external/qemu/fpu/softfloat.c:486:round_canonical: code should not be reached

    19:36   Emulator: Warning: QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread ((null):0, (null))

    19:36   ADB rejected shell command (getprop): closed

    19:36   Emulator: Process finished with exit code 3
```

I have no idea what this means but I know it has something to do with the update I downloaded, is there any way to roll back the update maybe?

Comment: Does a freshly created emulator work?

Comment: a freshly created emulator is not working, it isn't even saying android on load, it just stays black

Comment: it still crashes with the same error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've come across the same issue on Windows 10: the current version of Android Emulator (Nov 14, 2018: 28.0.16) crashes or freezes as soon as a virtual ARM device is started. When I start it from command line, it prints

> Emulator:
>   ERROR:/buildbot/src/android/emu-3.0-release/external/qemu/fpu/softfloat.c:486:round_canonical:
>   code should not be reached

As a temporary solution, I downgraded the emulator to an older version and the problem disappeared.

Here you can find Android Emulator 27.2.9:

- Windows: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-windows-4773671.zip
- Mac: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-darwin-4773671.zip
- Linux: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-linux-4773671.zip

Steps to downgrade the emulator:

1. Stop all instances of the emulator and close Android Studio;
2. Open Android SDK directory. Its location can be found in the settings: Android Studio->File->Settings->Appearance & Behavior->System Settings->Android SDK->Android SDK Location;
3. Move existing 'emulator' directory somewhere outside of Android SDK (if you just rename and leave it there, AVD Manager will find it and start using again);
4. Unpack one of emulator-*-4266726.zip into the SDK directory;
5. Launch Android Studio and don't update Android Emulator until it's fixed.

Related answer: [How to downgrade Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49284378/10651931)

Comment: Also fixes the problem on Ubuntu 14.04. In my case, the emulator just wouldn't finish booting and was behaving erratically.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across the same issue on Windows 10,I upgrade Android Emulator 28.0.16 to 28.0.20 also solve the error.