# Where to get this missing file - Android Studio , Emulator

Tags: android, linux

After upgrading my android studio -  I tried creating an emulator but get this error when trying to start the AVD :

```
Emulator: statvfs('/home/nompumelelo/.android/avd/Pixel_2_API_24.avd/snapshots/default_boot/ram.img') failed:
No such file or directory
```

I have restarted the android studio, recreated the AVD - but still no success.

The error below is what shows on my terminal.

Comment: is the emulator successfully created?

Comment: Try changing the emulator configuration to 'Cold Boot' (assuming it was quick boot which uses the snapshot) then start the emulator - once started you can change option back to quick-boot - it should save a new snapshot.

Comment: @Afhamu - the emulator gets created but it-s not functional.

Comment: @Andy: I tried the cold boot option, now the problem is with the space. I get this error not `Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Not enough space to create userdata partition. Available: 5528.578125 MB `

Comment: Ok what's the available memory space of your Local Drive C?

Comment: Its 5.8 GB - I am working on setting a smaller sized memory and storage, will tell you if it worked.

Comment: I am having the same issue, must be because of the latest update... oh google :(

Comment: I just downgraded my Emulator by putting the "emulator" folder (found in the zip) to the sdk folder (e.g. `/home/sufian/Android/Sdk` for me, or see your folder by going to settings and search for "SDK"). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49284378/1276636) provides the download link.

Comment: Someone has reported this on the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141143926).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that the [Emulator 29.2.1 Stable](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/09/emulator-2921-stable.html) fixes this bug.

An excerpt from the link above:

> Fixed [crash on startup on Linux Wayland systems](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/d6gnrn/android_emulator_2920_crashes_on_fedora_wayland/). This was because
>   XkbGetKeyboard was used to query the host system's keyboard state. It
>   seems usage of XkbGetKeyboard is not advisable on Linux and perhaps in
>   general: https://github.com/glfw/glfw/issues/389

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem using XWayland, after switching to X11 it worked again.