# Cannot run non-x86 arch in Android Studio emulator

Tags: android, arm, emulation

First of all, my bug is similar with this one: [Where to get this missing file - Android Studio , Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57421780/where-to-get-this-missing-file-android-studio-emulator)

While for all, I installed the latest sdk info in android studio:
[image]

The thing is I can only run x86/x86_64 image AVD in my computer. These images works well. But when I try to use other, take arm for example, things don't work out, the AVD just hang there and command output

```
上午11:33 Emulator: statvfs('/home/f0rm2l1n/.android/avd/Pixel_aarch.avd/snapshots/default_boot/ram.img') failed: No such file or directory

上午11:33 Emulator: Warning: QXcbIntegration: Cannot create platform OpenGL context, neither GLX nor EGL are enabled ((null):0, (null))

上午11:33 Emulator: queryCoreProfileSupport: swap interval not found
```

I tried with choosing *Cold Boot* and *Raising RAM & Storage*. But it is not solved.

Any suggestions will help? I just want to run a AArch64 AVD for homework XD