# Android Studio Emulator - Location Routes not working since updating to Emulator 30.0.26

Tags: android, android-studio, kml

I am trying to use routes to test an application. I am using Android Studio 4.0.1 and emulator version 30.0.26. When I play a route it looks like it plays the first location and then two seconds after the Lat Lon change to the last location on the route. It is as thought Android emulator only recognises the first and last position.

The developer is using Android Studio 4.0.1 and emulator version 29.0.11, the same KML files and everything looks good on his system. He even gets a window that lists all the locations in the route.

I have tried to downgrade the emulator as per this post ([How to downgrade Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49120854/how-to-downgrade-android-emulator)) however Android realises that the emulator has been changed, deletes it and asks to install the new version.

I noticed in the release notes for Emulator 30.0.26 this general fix "Fixed gpx/kml route playback to follow timestamps". I assume that this means I am now required to have timestamps in my KML file. I tried my best to update the data and Emulator did not like the new file. I have also tried various tutorials on how to make KML files without any luck.

I have tried the "Showing Movement of a Point Along a Path" date set at the below link, it does the same thing. https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/time

Does anyone know how to revert Emulator?
Is there an example KML file somewhere that I could use as a reference to confirm that Emulator is working and use as a template to update my data?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing with the same problem. With the new emulator version you have to add the timestamps into kml/gpx file.
I used this website: https://gotoes.org/strava/Add_Timestamps_To_GPX.php
and it's working fine for me now!

Comment: Thank you for the response Carles. I found out that the extended controls / Location window does not update when the devices location changes. Also for some AVD models the location features do not work at all. I found that I could use the map app for location feedback and then find a virtual device that did work with locations (the app that I was testing did not give me feedback about its location). I also was able to use the telnet interface to change the devices location. Thanks again.

Comment: I was very hopeful  this would work for me but it still just says "Loading Saved Route" forever. I need this to work!