# Android Emulator 30.2.6 crash on iMac 2011

Tags: sdk, android-emulator

today I updated my android emulator to the last stable version, 30.2.6, and you can imagine my face when I saw that there is no option to run any emulator, always crash. My teammate is using a similar iMac than me, iMac 2011 with macOS 10-13.6 and he has the same problem.

Can you tell me how to downgrade to a previous emulator version?

PS: I have tested next canary version 30.3.1 and it is not working.
PS2: I can start emulator with graphics emulated by software, but this is not a performance option.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be issue related to 30.2.6 running on old mac.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/172946954

However when I downgrade my Android Emulator, it works again. Here is how to do it.

1. Download an archive version of Emulator and unarchive, here I use 30.1.2 (Not specific reason, just a random old version)
   http://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-darwin-6800617.zip
2. Backup the package.xml in ~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator
3. Replace the main emulator directory: mv ~/Downloads/emulator ~/Library/Android/sdk/
4. paste the package.xml in step 2 back.
5. Restart Android Studio

credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49284378/9589380