# Cannot start Android Emulator - Library not loaded

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I updated the Android Emulator in Android Studio. After the update i always get "The emulator process was killed" when i try to start an AVD.

I tried to start it from command line and get following error.

> emulator: Android emulator version 30.5.3.0 (build_id 7196367) (CL:N/A)
> dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/IOUSBHost.framework/Versions/A/IOUSBHost
> Referenced from: /Users/NaoKreuzeder/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64
> Reason: image not found
> Abort trap: 6

I searched for file "IOUSBHost.framework" on my mac. But could not find it.

How to solve this? Can someone point me in the right direction to find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After i updated MacOS to Catalina (10.15.7) everything works fine now.
Looks like, newest version of Android Studio Emulator don´t work with older MacOS Versions.

Answer (score 5):

I do not have a solution to provide, but I can confirm that the problem appears in the following configuration:

- macos High Sierra (10.13.6),
- AndroidStudio 4.1.3,
- Android Emulator 30.5.3,
- HAXM 7.6.5

I can also confirm that in newer version of macsos like Big Sure (11.2.3) with the same versions of development tools everything works fine, because the IOUSBHost.framework exists.

From Apple developer website https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iousbhost/iousbhostdevice we can see that the framework IOUSBHost is available from version macOS 10.15 and above.

Comment: Please make use of text formatting, particularly of the list in your answer.

Answer (score 4):

My Mac is running Mojave and I ran into this problem after upgrading my Android Emulator version to v30.5.3 today. I downgraded my emulator version from v30.5.3 to v30.0.12 and that resolved the issue.

Comment: How did you  downgraded emulator version from v30.5.3 to v30.0.12?

Comment: Using below link I downgraded my emulator, and now I am able to run my Android Emulator. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/183218284#comment3. Use this emulator setup https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-darwin-6855416.zip it is 30.1.5, which supports API 30.

Comment: Please note that we need to copy the package.xml from the older emulator as mentioned in the comments to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49284378/2102114